# Can't make <h1> element display on the same line as navigation links?

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

"Old" Newbie here. I have not been coding css or html in about 10 years now. Use to be good at it and really like doing it as well. So now during covid and lockdown I decided to get back at it again. Currently just re-learning everything, and trying to build up a website from scratch.

Having some issues with getting menu/navigation links in position on the same line as my h1 title. Have tried about everything, like ex. display: inline-block; and also read a lot of posts here. But nothing seems to be working. So I hope somebody here that have any suggestions?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please supply us with your HTML and CSS, otherwise, we can just guess.

Comment: Welcome back to coding and welcome here. On Stackoverflow it is a good practice to add code so you can get help. As @GhostPengy mentioned: HTML and CSS would be helpful in this case. You can do so edditing your question and add the code blocks in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the tag h1, you'll see there is a standard margin bottom which the browser applied to h1 tag. You can erase it directly on inspect window, I guess that is your problem. =))

Comment: I've build the html and css from scratch, so there is no standard margin bottom. So that can't be the problem. but thank you so much for the suggestion :)

Comment: Oh! Maybe I guessed wrong your problem, so I think you should learn about flex to do resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a div which contains both your nav items and the header, this should use display:flex and align-items: center, the justify-content will set the horizontal alignment of everything inside this container

Then float the nav to the left, and they should be aligned, from here you can add as much styles as you want

Good luck!

```css
.barContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: helvetica;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 15px;
}

nav {
  background-position: center;
  padding: 1%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: orange;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

nav li, nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="barContainer">
  <nav>
    <a href="item1.html">Item 1</a>
    <a href="item2.html">Item 2</a>
    <a href="item3.html">Item 3</a>
  </nav>
  <h1>My Header</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **float** property to float elements within a parent element. Choose right or left to choose which side the element will float to. When this property is used, the **display** property of the floating elements is ignored when using block, inline, or inline-block.

In the parent element, use the **overflow: hidden** property, so that it will be at the same height as the largest element contained in it. When a parent element only has floating elements inside it, and does not use the **overflow: hidden property**, its height will be 0 and the elements below will overlap it.

```css
.content {
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.menu {
    float:right;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.menu li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 10px;
}

h1 {
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class='content'>
    <h1>My Title</h1>
    <nav class='menu'>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>  
    </nav>
</div>
```